# Xcode set Bool with buttons

Tags: xcode, cocoa, binding, boolean

I am trying to create a simple set of buttons which show/hide a text field.
I created a BOOL in .h;

```
BOOL showBool;
@property BOOL showBool;
```

Then have buttons linked to actions in .h:

```
- (IBAction) showText:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) hideText:(id)sender;
```

Then in .m, I have the actions, which *should* be setting the bool;

```
- (IBAction) showText:(id)sender;
{
    showBool = YES;
}

- (IBAction) hideText:(id)sender;
{
showBool = NO;
}
```

I have a text field key value bound via App Delegate as 'hidden' to showBool.  But it does not change (hide/show) during run...

Am I setting the booleans incorrectly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings rely on key value observing. Use the accessor  `self.showBool = YES;` to trigger the change for the binding, rather than directly giving the ivar a value. This assumes you did the `@synthesize` in your implementation.